# Does btrfs support thin provisioning and quota management like zfs?

Tags: filesystem, btrfs

I checked the btrfs command and didn't find anything related to thiese features.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommended ext4 or xfs on machines you really want to use. iirc brtfs will support quotas,but it's still under heavy development.